# data table is not working on my table in view page in mvc

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, view, datatable

i want to make table as datatable but its not applying in my table. datatable is working in static table but while im adding dynamic table its not showing any datatable features like search option and paging. all the records showing at time even though its selected 10 in the paging .

code

```
   <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').DataTable();
            });
        </script>


    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>deviceid</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>UpdatedTime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>deviceid</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>UpdatedTime</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deviceid)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedTime)</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
}
</table>
```

Comment: i have already referenced js and css files of datatable.while replacing the static table with some content its showing datable but not working with dynamic table.console error- TypeError: c is undefined

Comment: i checked. in my code i have closed table tag. my issue is table is showing all the records instead of showing records as per the paging dropdown value and search option also not working .i think may be need to change @foreach loop .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you add all of the following**

```
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

**Example link**: https://jsfiddle.net/r8gd2227/3/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });
```

Comment: im my real code i used the proper id for table. i have updated my question with the id . still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>deviceid</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>UpdatedTime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>deviceid</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>UpdatedTime</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
         <tr >
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deviceid)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdatedTime)</td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```